# Facebook Canvas APIs to SetSize Completely Broken

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently trying to solve an issue so that my facebook application is resized appropriately as it is currently getting cut off before the bottom (Aka you can't scroll to the bottom of my hosted app using the scrollbar.) I have spent a lot of time trying to figure out this issue so any help would be appreciated. Currently my calls to FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 2000 }); return true however nothing happens and I still cant reach the bottom of my app.  I even tried calling on a button click however I still get the same result.

**Update:** After trying some ideas, I was able to get this to work if I load the Facebook SDK sync into my homepage and call setSize there.  However I still am not having any luck when it is loaded Async or Sync into a different page that my canvas navigates to? Just setting the size on my homepage won't work since each page has a different size. Has anyone seen issues like this

Here is the code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
   appId      : 'XXXXXXXXX', // App ID
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
   xfbml      : false  // parse XFBML
  });

  FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: $(document).width(), height: $(document).height() });

  setFriends();
};

(function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));


$(document).ready(function() {
  if (FB && FB.Canvas) {
    FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: $(document).width(), height: $(document).height() });
  }
});
```

Comment: Similar problem, found it interesting that $(document) height/width are the dimensions of the iframe and not the actual source page.  Atleast for Chrome for Mac that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem creating an app for a client.  I couldn't get the scroll bars to drop.  Finally got those to go away and then had the same issue as you with it cutting off the bottom of my app.  Here's the the link to the forum post at which I found it.  Facebook changed just a bit of code:

Instead of `FB.Canvas.setSize()` it's now `FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()`.

Hope it helps.

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8559679/remove-horizontal-and-vertical-scrollbar-from-facebook-apps

Comment: I'll try using setAutoGrow today.  I really was hoping to explicitly set the size since it doesn't change outside of page load. I didn't want to have the extra perf costs of Facebook checking for resize every time interval and changing the size based off of that.

Answer (score 0):

I usually call setSize without any parameters and that seems to work for me.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
```

What do you have your Canvas height set to in the advanced app settings? I found using "fluid" caused problems and had to set it to "Settable (Default: 800px)".

Comment: Nope that didn't seem to work either for me. I have my height set to Settable (Default: 800px) and my width set to Fluid. I tried both Fluid and Fixed for Width and neither worked.

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors on the page? Maybe put an alert after the setSize so you know it ran. I'm assuming you don't have dynamic content loading that would change the size (use setAutoGrow then).

Comment: Yep, I set an alert and verified that the function was running and that it was returning true as expected.  I am thinking this might be do to this code not running on the homepage?  The start page works great but when I nav to my other app pages this no longer works.  Could that be a potential source of the problem?

Comment: you have to call it on every page load.

Comment: I did call it on ever page load but only the first page load seemed to work. Note: I also use ssl and https for loading my pages if that is any issue.  I changed the facebook script reference to https but that didnt help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I really was hoping to explicitly set the size since it doesn't change outside of page load. I didn't want to have the extra perf costs of Facebook checking for resize every time interval and changing the size based off of that.

Good call. This advice from http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-iframe-apps-getting-rid-of-scrollbars/

To reduce your users CPU cycles, you can also use the setSize function.

FB.Canvas.setSize

Once you’ve loaded the Javascript SDK, you can use FB.Canvas.setSize() to get rid of those scrollbars. Put the following code before the closing HEAD tag on your index page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1400 });
}
</script>
```

This tells Facebook to resize your iFrame once the page has loaded and again whenever the size of your content changes.

Again, these functions will only work if you set your Canvas Height to “Settable.”